# Can you set multiple ACLs with google cloud storage resumable URLs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create a resumable url with this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert). Here is what it looks like:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucket/o`

In the documentation it says you can also specify a `predefinedAcl` as a query parameter. For example:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o?name=objectName&uploadType=resumable&predefinedAcl=publicRead`

My question is can you specify **multiple** `predefinedAcl`s? I tried the following two methods to set a query param array but it did not work:

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o?name=objectName&uploadType=resumable&predefinedAcl=publicRead&predefinedAcl=bucketOwnerFullControl`

`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/bucketname/o?name=objectName&uploadType=resumable&predefinedAcl=publicRead,bucketOwnerFullControl`

I want the object to have both the public read ACL and also have all authenticated users (i.e. the bucket owner) have owner access.

In Java it would be an array of: `Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllUsers(), Acl.Role.READER)` and `Acl.of(Acl.User.ofAllAuthenticatedUsers(), Acl.Role.OWNER)'`

How can I set that in this resumable url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set a single predefined ACL. If you want finer grain access control you need to set either an IAM policy or a (non-predefined) ACL.